# How can I transform a pandas df to this kind of json structure?

Tags: python, json, pandas, to-json, convertto-json

Let's say I have a pandas `df` like this:

```
| name   | color of clothing | age |occupation|
| John   | yellow            | 34  | janitor  |
| Carl   | red               | 27  | doctor   |
| Claire | green             | 33  | teacher  |
| Lisa   | blue              | 21  | Student  |
|........|...................| ....|..........|
```

I would like to transform it in a json format like this:

```
[
{ "name": "John,
"color of clothing": "yellow",
"age":"34",
"occupation": "janitor"
},
{ "name": "Carl",
"color of clothing": "red",
"age":"27",
"occupation": "doctor"
},
{ "name": "Claire",
"color of clothing": "green",
"age":"33",
"occupation": "teacher"
},
{ "name": "Lisa",
"color of clothing": "blue",
"age":"21",
"occupation": "student"
}
]
```

How can I do this? The nearest match I had was using `df.to_json(orient="index")` but what I've got was a structure like this:

```
{"0":{ "name": "John,
"color of clothing": "yellow",
"age":"34",
"occupation": "janitor"
}
},
"1":{ "name": "Carl",
"color of clothing": "red",
"age":"27",
"occupation": "doctor"
}}
...
```

Would be really thankful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.to_dict('records')`

```
>>> df
   a  b  c  d
0  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2
>>> df.to_dict('records')
[{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 1}, {'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 2}]
```